# Get the Current Notebook URl

Tags: python, apache-zeppelin

I need to get the current url of zeppilin notebook to fetch the query string parameters, I am getting from the UI

I have tried all the things which I can do in python But none is worked

I am getting only the hostname  with the below code

```
os.environ.get("HOSTNAME")
```

But I want the complete URL of the Notebook

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you add more details and examples as well?

Comment: Url='10.1.12.144:9000/dataset=first, second/

Comment: So when I tried with os.environ.get(hostname) I am getting 10.1.12.144

Comment: I need to get the whole url so that I can fetch the parameters for dataset

Comment: But I didn't see os.environ.get(query-string) key in Zeppelin notebook

Comment: Anyone have an idea  on this

Comment: That won't work as the python code is executed on the server and zeppelin doesn't provide a function as far as I know to get the current URL. You could use javascript with the [angular backend]('https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/displaysystem/back-end-angular.html') instead.

Comment: I have tried to get the parameters from url using angular in one paragragraph, and in another paragraph and I am doing some operations by taking that parameters, but nothing working on that parameter.